# ext: news with rx_shariff - facebook shared news return problem

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, tx-news

I use TYPO3 8.7 and NEWS extension 6.3 and shariff-sharing.
When i share a news record on Facebook the publication goes well, but when i tried to go back to news record i get 404 error. I think the problem is a query parameter called attach to outbound links by Facebook and appearing in the news record URL. Something like  http://example.com/newstitle/?fbclid=IwAR2QIndkh'. What i must do to correct this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Wolffc already noted, you need to add the parameter to TYPO3's cHash excluded parameters.

If you use realurl, you also need to tell realurl about it. The current master contains a change for that https://github.com/dmitryd/typo3-realurl/commit/2f1dfced4a2f64656f4091ab79ab307ff6daa469 - that makes realurl reconfigure TYPO3 to include the parameter.

Until it gets released, I suggested a common configuration that I use my realurl configuration (let realurl use the TYPO3 conf) here:
https://github.com/dmitryd/typo3-realurl/pull/650

Comment: It works! I add the parameter to install tool and applied master change of realurl. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need ro add fbclid to the chash ignored parameters in the install tool

Comment: I added fbclid at chash parameter in [FE][cHashExcludedParameters] and nothing happened.
I still get error, page not found, error Reason: Request parameters could not be validated (&cHash empty).
(i clean all caches)
Thanks